# third table with all two table informations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have one table for users (userid is the pk) and a second table for items (itemid is the pk)
I need to have those two tables into one table, how could I do that in phpmyadmin?

[image]

Comment: please paste the code/sample data  instead of screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you cna use `left join lateral` :

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM USERS
LEFT JOIN LATERAL 
  ( select * from  ITEMS) ITEMS
ON 1 = 1
WHERE userid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `cross join`:

```
select u.*, i.*
from users u cross join
     items i
where u.userid = 1;
```